# NLTK Concordance between delimiters

Tags: python, nltk, custom-formatting

I am using Python and NLTK to analyse some 'goal' titles. Basically, people set some goals such as 'work harder', 'watch the sun rise' and so on. What I want to do is see how and where each of the non-stopwords appear in the list of entries and dump the results into a file. I know that I can give 'concordance' a width, and that helps a little (helps me prune unimportant data out of the output).

Ideally what I want to do is show concordances from comma to comma (one 'goal' entry is separated by commas). I know I could maybe use a search to do this rather than nltk, but the nltk package is much more elegant and I would like to use it, if possible.